# Как сделать таймер на C++

Tags: c++, функции, sleep

Делаю игру змейку, изучая ООП C++, и есть код:

```
while (true) {
    snake.Move();
    sleep(150); // задержка в 150 миллисекунд
}
```

Как сделать эту самую функцию "sleep()" ?
ОС - Linux

Answer (score 4):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184468/sleep-for-milliseconds

Средствами стандартной библиотеки.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

В linux есть готовая функция usleep, которая "усыпляет" поток на заданное количество микросекунд. Для ее использования требуется подключить

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

вы можете использовать ее так

```
usleep(150000);
```

Comment: Причём тут Linux? POSIX — правильное слово. Да, POSIX же рекомендует или `sleep()` или `nanosleep()`.

Comment: Автор спрашивал про linux

Comment: OK, всё же более обобщённый ответ лучше.